# Is there a better way to change the cursor? Am I doing it right?

Tags: javascript, css, cursor, hover, anchor

I was just using some javascript the other day, and previously, the only way I knew how to get it to display the cursor was to do this:

## 1:

```
<a href="javascript:" onClick="myfunction()"></a>
```

But I decided to find some other ways to do it. Not wanting to have my css messy and all over the place, I added this to my stylesheet:

## 2:

```
a{
    cursor:pointer
}
```

I'm not styling non-link anchors anywhere else. Is it okay to style non-link anchors?

## 3:

Or is there a way I should being doing it with javascript that's better then the two ways listed above.

Comment: He added code formatting to your first example (it was not visible before because it tried to display it as a link rather than HTML code).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey some browsers call the cursor a pointer, others call it a hand (forgot which ones which). So what you have to do is

```
.pointable
{
    cursor: pointer;
    cursor: hand;
}
```

**Edit:**

I like to make a css style called pointable and applying it to whatever elements I want pointable.

```
<div class="box pointable rounded">dggf</div>
<a class="pointable">sdds</a>
```

Comment: Hand was made by IE and *was never an officially supported value by CSS standards*. Unless you're trying to support IE5, don't add that line. Pointer is supported in basically every browser except IE < 6.

Comment: Umm, yea, I was not sure which the browser was, I guess it should've been obvious. But I used to have this problem even in IE 6 i think, so I've always done it this way. It never hurts though, just an extra line for the people still stuck in the past.

Answer (score 1):

As long as this does not get in the way of how you style the `<a>` tag anywhere else on your page this is the best way to do it.

Comment: @Jackson - I could not see the text on #1 -- so I moved it down a line an in so it escaped it as code.

Comment: You can see what was edited by clicking the "edited __ ago" link.

Answer (score 0):

All `<a>` tags should have an `href` attribute even if it is blank or says `javascript:;`.
So I recommend option 1.

Comment: Anchors are not required to have a href attribute. Please read the specs.